# On the second geometric form of Hahn-Banach´s theorem (Brezis, theorem 1.7) I dont know if im understanding this inequality correctly

Tags: functional-analysis

f is a functional.
$f(x-y)\leq f(rz),$     $\forall x\in A,$ $\forall y\in B$, $\forall z\in B(0,1)$

Then

$f(x-y)\leq -r ||f||,$     $\forall x\in A,$ $\forall y\in B$

The problem is with the sign of the r

is it because the z is on the B(0,1) so the inverse vectors of the z´s are there too and we can use both z or -z?

Comment: What you have said is correct, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it in this way.
Your relation gives
$$
f(x-y) \leq \inf_{z\in B(0,1)} f(rz), \qquad \forall x\in A,\ \forall y\in B.
$$
On the other hand, since $B(0,1)$ is symmetric w.r.t. the origin,
$$
\inf_{z\in B(0,1)} f(rz) =
\inf_{z\in B(0,1)} [-r \, f(-z)]
= -r \sup_{z\in B(0,1)} f(-z)
= -r \sup_{z\in B(0,1)} f(z)
= -r \|f\|.
$$

Comment: Really nice, thank you very much!